# Sources (other than tutorials) on Game Mechanics

Tags: game-mechanics, documentation

But, I'm not quite sure where I should start from here. I know I have to go and grab an engine to use with some prebuilt libraries, and then from there learn how to actually code a game, etc. All I have right now is some "program Tetris" tutorial for C++ open right now, but I'm not even sure if that will really help me with what I want to accomplish.

I'm curious if there are is any good C++ documentation related to game development which provides information on building a game in more of a component model (by this I'm referring to the documentation, not the actual object-oriented design of the game itself), rather than an entire tutorial designed to do something specific. This could include information based on various design methodologies, or how to link hardware with OpenGL interfaces, or just simply even learning how to render 2D images on a canvas.

I suppose this place is definitely a good source :P, but what I'm looking for is quite a bit of information - and I think posting a new question every ten minutes would just flood the site...

Comment: -1, too broad a topic, really.

Comment: Well, see that's the problem: I don't really know what to look for. Maybe you could point me in the right direction, or suggest something to search for, rather than just -1 my topic and tell me I didn't ask the question properly. It's not like I would do something like that on purpose. Why so harsh?

Comment: He's not being harsh, just being honest :) If anybody in here assembles an answer worthy of such a broad question, it's worth 100 upvotes. Generally there are no such things such "General documentary on C++ game programming", since most if not all problems in game design are really problem specific. The closest you could get to what you want would be to get some source for using design patterns in games, but even design patterns are just rough tools that you should know in order to have an idea on how to structure code, not something you can implement 1:1.

Comment: The problem is we don't even know which direction to point you in. The question is all over the place really, it mentions game mechanics, component models, opengl rendering and documentation. Try to minimize your question down to the thing you need answering. Sorry if it sounds harsh. If you're just looking to get started with game development there are already a lot of relevant questions.

Comment: Ok, I'll just check those out then. Thanks, and sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i started to place a comment bt it went to long so changed it to an answer :

first of all you have specify your target platform, and it would also help if you tell which genre are you going to create a game. the brad answer is to download and install dx SDK if you are going to develop for microsoft group or opengl sdk if you are going to develop for others. there are many sample codes with enough documentation inside each sdk.

or you can just pick a game engine again based on the genre and platform you are going to create your game and start reading that engine's specific manual. studying a engine help you create your games easier but will take you a lot more time until you reach the point that you can start your games from the scrach( and blieve me starting to develop a gameengine is almost always a bad idea). for stat I suggest essenthel engine. it comes out with a lot of samples and an active community and it's very easy to use almost the easiest engine i've ever seen in c++ and it's also free unless you want to publish a game with it. but it needs a lot of c++ knowledge to begin with and one might consider it as a moderate engine compared to UDK or similar gigantic engines.

--edit--

esenthel engine has only target platform of pc and mac and if you are a license developer you can also create games for ipad/iphone. for an opensource game development i recommend taking a look on ogre3D, it's an opensource engine and even there is chapter in "deitel & deitel: c++ how to program" about it. but as far as I know (I didn't try that engine myself) it's almost somevery basic framework which force you to add many conecpts of your game yourself. And I think givving a bigger challange you can learn a lot more if you really get into it.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, and will definitely look into that. As far as platforms go, it would be mainly just P.C. and open source (mainly Linux, since that's all I run right now).

Answer (score -1):

Its questions like these, is why I wrote this (check link) and guess what it got closed and voted down.  Anyway I hope it is of some use to you.

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12892/education-paths-to-game-programming-dev-on-windows-linux-june-2011

The most important part of that link is that I recommend you "Game Coding Complete", its near the bottom of the link I gave.

Comment: -1. Don't put the answer in a link, as links can die, and in this case the link is already dead.